Switching or changing Sheets using a drop down that has date ranges for the data
I can't seem to figure out why this doesn't work.  When I choose the drop down selection that should activate or trigger the vba code, nothing happens.  I have the below code under Sheet1 which is named (2Weeks) (...right click and pasted in view code window for that sheet). That’s all the code I have… no modules at the moment.  I have (General) for the Object choice and (ListBox1_Change) (which is the drop down list in cell B4), for the Procedure. B4 is a cell with a drop down list with a bunch of date ranges (see below) like these two…  (08/01/2024 - 08/18/2024, 11/11/2024 - 12/01/2024).  I did complete the Data Validation correctly for cell B4... choosing List and the Date Ranges as the references, etc. By the way, must I have a combo box instead of a list box to make this code work?  The two date ranges listed above, if selected, should change to a different sheet, Sheet2, which is named 3Weeks, from the current one. And when switched to the other sheet, the user would be on cell B4 of the new sheet, if possible. The two sheet names are sheet1=2Weeks and sheet2=3Weeks. Would anyone be able to fix this or come up with a totally different code to accomplish this?  Also, am I allowed to have the OR statement in between the dates so if the user chooses either date it triggers the vba code?  Can there be more than two dates to trigger the VBA?  If so, would there be more OR statements in the code? (By the way, there is no tag for Change-Worksheet or Worksheet-Change or something similar so the tags are lacking, unfortunately.)
Private Sub ListBox1_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Range("B4"), Target) Is Nothing) Then _
        ThisWorkbook.2Weeks(Target.Value = "08/01/2024 - 08/18/2024" OR Target.Value = "11/11/2024 - 12/01/2024").Range("B4").Activate
    End If
End Sub```

The B4 cell drop down references L3:L23 and looks like this: 
07/15/2024 - 07/31/2024
08/01/2024 - 08/18/2024
08/19/2024 - 09/01/2024
09/02/2024 - 09/15/2024
09/16/2024 - 09/29/2024
09/30/2024 - 10/13/2024
10/14/2024 - 10/27/2024
10/28/2024 - 11/10/2024
11/11/2024 - 12/01/2024
11/30/2024 - 12/13/2024
12/14/2024 - 12/31/2024 …etc.

